# MySqlDataReader returns the same value for all the rows in the table

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am using MySql with C#.
I have this code:

```
    public List<Student> selectStudent()
    {
        List<Student> stud = new List<Student>();
        Student st = new Student();
        MySqlConnection msConn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        MySqlDataReader msRdr = null; ;
        try
        {
            msConn.Open();
            MySqlCommand msComm = new MySqlCommand();

            msComm.Connection = msConn;
            msComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Student";
            msRdr = msComm.ExecuteReader();
            while (msRdr.Read())
            {
                st.ID = msRdr.GetInt32(0);
                st.Name = msRdr.GetString(1);
                st.Address = msRdr.GetString(3);
                st.Birthdate = msRdr.GetDateTime(2);
                stud.Add(st);
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e) { }
        finally {
            msRdr.Close();
            msConn.Close(); };

        return stud;
    }
```

My problem is that in the data table I have 3 rows, for example
1 Jake Walker ...the rest of columns
2 Raymond West ...the rest of columns
3 Anne Marie Johnson ...the rest of columns

But when I put the in such a list List and then bind the list to a combobox, I get same value for all the 3 rows of the dropdown and if I print the values of the list I get only one value. And the value I get is the third: the already annoying Anne Marie Johnson.

Comment: your problem appears to be in this line `Student st = new Student();` since you are in a while loop you need to add this `Student st = new Student();` as the first line in the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep overwriting the properties of your one instance of `st` that you allocate in the line

```
Student st = new Student();
```

Rather than allocating `st` outside of the loop, allocate a new one for each loop iteration

```
while (msRdr.Read())
{
    Student st = new Student();

    st.ID = msRdr.GetInt32(0);
    st.Name = msRdr.GetString(1);
    st.Address = msRdr.GetString(3);
    st.Birthdate = msRdr.GetDateTime(2);
    stud.Add(st);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I should've seen it but I didn't. I usually don't make this kind of mistakes.

Comment: That kind of thing happens to the best of us.